# Characters & Strings in Printf

Tags: c

I'm going through an exercise book on C and came across the statement

```
printf("%c", "\n");
```

Which when run in a console still works but displays the "$" symbol.

Why did this statement not crash the console like

```
printf("%s", '\n');
```

does?

Comment: This is [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939)  , anything may happen

Comment: Undefined behavior does not necessarily always cause a crash. Sometimes you get random output instead. Sometimes other undefined things happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a double quoted string like that produces a value of a pointer to `char`  (aka `char*`),  while the single quote produce a value that's a character (using the ASCII value of whats in the quotes.   On some compilers you can stack multiple characters into the single quotes.

```
printf("%c", *("\n") );
```

would print your linefeed, as the `*` operator would dereference the pointer

( You could probably do `*"\n"` , I just tend to be conservative in writing expressions)

```
printf("%s", '\n');
```

crashes because `%s` expects a pointer,  and  a linefeed cast into a pointer is pointing off in the weeds and most likely causes an invalid memory access

Answer (score 3):

It will invoke *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type. It just *happened* not to crash.

In some implementation, the pointer converted from the string literal is passed as an argument. Unlike `%s`, which will interpret the argument as pointer and go to read thete, `%c` will just take the argument as a number and print it, so it has less chance to crash.

Answer (score 2):

Because `%s` expects a `NUL` terminated string where `%c` only wants a char.  The string will read past the end of your buffer (the single char) looking for that `NUL` and quite likely cause a memory exception.  Or not - hence undefined behavior.

Comment: The first example tries to interpret a pointer as a `char`.  The second tries to treat an `int` as a pointer... but the problem isn't the missing null, it's dereferencing an invalid pointer and trying to print what it points to.

Answer (score 0):

Only the latter statement asked the implementation to dereference an invalid pointer. An invalid value will typically show as garbage. But most possible memory location values are inaccessible and attempting to access them will cause a crash on modern operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

%s prints until it reaches a '\0' because \n has no escape it will read into memory. "%c" only needs a char

Comment: in this case where it starts reading is probably more toxic (as in causing an exception) than what it would be reading, absent the exception. On simpler memory models (like 16 bit DOS), most likely that %s `printf` would just dump some garbage based on the contents of memory starting at address 0x000a